# Polish letters in sorting select2

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

With the help of @Rory McCrossan managed to create such a script to sort the values in the select field. However, there is still a problem - support for Polish characters. Is there any possibility to also be taken into account?

Code:

```
var dataUser = [{
    "id": "5",
    "text": "BTest"
}, {
    "id": "2",
    "text": "ATest"
}, {
    "id": "8",
    "text": "aTest"
}, {
    "id": "13",
    "text": "ŁTest"
}];

var dataUser2 = [{
    "id": "5",
    "text": "DBTest"
}, {
    "id": "2",
    "text": "FATest"
}];

$("#mylist").select2({
    data: dataUser,
    templateResult: function(data) {
        return data.text;
    },
    sorter: function(data) {
        return data.sort(function(a, b) {
            return a.text.toLowerCase() < b.text.toLowerCase() ? -1 : a.text.toLowerCase() > b.text.toLowerCase() ? 1 : 0;
        });
    }
}).on("select2:select", function(e) {
    var $container = $(this).next().find('.select2-selection__rendered');
    $container.find('li.select2-selection__choice').sort(function(a, b) {
        return $(a).text() < $(b).text() ? -1 : $(a).text() > $(b).text() ? 1 : 0;
    }).prependTo($container);
});

$("#mylist2").select2({
    data: dataUser2,
    templateResult: function(data) {
        return data.text;
    },
    sorter: function(data) {
        return data.sort(function(a, b) {
            return a.text.toLowerCase() < b.text.toLowerCase() ? -1 : a.text.toLowerCase() > b.text.toLowerCase() ? 1 : 0;
        });
    }
});
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/oe9retsL/12/)

Comment: In other words, you want to sort as "ATest,BTest,ŁTest,atest"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use String.localeCompare instead of < see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare

```
sort(function(a, b) {
    return $(a).text().localeCompare($(b).text());
});
```

Comment: You're right, thank You for your response solutions :)

Comment: Old one but I've just stumbled upon this issue. For polish language (and so I guess - any other language besides english) it is important to actually specify language code, because if you will not, then browser will decide for you and it might give different results between browsers (in my case it was difference between node and browsers).

Just specify the second argument like this `a.localeCompare(b, 'pl')`
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare